# popup window not moving like facebook comment/like popup window do

Tags: android, popup

i want to move and dismiss my popup window like facebook comment/like popup window do. i tried myself and searched but failed. can you please help me to do so.

my code:

```
int display_width=context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                int display_height=context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

                final PopupWindow popupWindow=new PopupWindow(viewTmp_comment, display_width, display_height-60,true);
                popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);

                popupWindow.setInputMethodMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);
                popupWindow.showAsDropDown(view);
                popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                popupWindow.setTouchable(true);
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                popupWindow.setContentView(view);

                popupWindow.getContentView().setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {

                        switch (dragEvent.getAction()) {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                Toast.makeText(context,"Down",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                popupWindow.dismiss();
                                break;

//                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
//                        Toast.makeText(context,"Up",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
////                      popupWindow.dismiss();
//                        break;
                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

The facebook dialog goes up so you have to translate it from current position to top

```
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="-30%p"
    android:duration="1000" />
```

it's about the animation, you should take a look  : [Android animation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html)

update : 
define your style : e.g

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"> <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyAnimation.Windo‌​w</item> </style> <style name="MyAnimation.Window" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity"> <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item> </style>
```

and set popupWindow.setAnimationStyle( R.style.DialogTheme) not R.anim

Comment: window not moving a bit

Comment: have you added the animation to your dialog view?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="100%p"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:duration="400" />

</set>

Comment: popupWindow.getContentView().setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener()
switch (dragEvent.getAction()) {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                               
                                popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.anim.bottom_down);
                                break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        
                        break;
                        }

Comment: you have to define a style for your dialog : e.g  :
    <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyAnimation.Window</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyAnimation.Window" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item>
    </style>
and set popupWindow.setAnimationStyle( R.style.DialogTheme) not R.anim

Comment: did you call dismiss method?

Comment: dear its not moving a bit this is the main problem.,.,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142818/discussion-between-linh-nguyen-and-aaa).

Comment: please have u found a solution, i am also in a similar situation